# Monthly variance per Month by client and product. python

Tags: python, pandas, diff

##### updated data sample

I have below data frame, I need to calculate the variance per Month by client and category.
the issue with my code: in forth row and column DiffA I'm getting value zero instead of 1782207 (because it is an increment in that Month)
I guess because client didnt have product category = A in the previous Month the code is not working. any idea how to fix this.

I'm trying below code

```
df.sort_values(by=['Name','Category','Date'], inplace=True)
df['DiffB'] = df[df['Category'] == B].groupby('Name')['amount'].diff().fillna(0)
df['DiffA'] = df[df['Category'] == A].groupby('Name')['amount'].diff().fillna(0)
```

but I'm getting below output

| Name | Category | Date | Amount | DiffB | DiffA |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| ABC | B | 2023-04 | 1829540 | 0 | 0 |
| ABC | B | 2023-05 | 1829540 | 0 | 0 |
| ABC | B | 2023-06 | 12087873 | 10258333 | 0 |
| ABC | A | 2023-07 | 1782207 | 0 | **0** |
| ABC | B | 2023-07 | 10258333 | -1829540 | 0 |

Data sample

```
data = [
    ["ABC", "B", "2023-04", 1829540],
    ["ABC", "B", "2023-05", 1829540],
    ["ABC", "B", "2023-06", 12087873],
    ["ABC", "A", "2023-07", 1782207],
    ["ABC", "B", "2023-07", 10258333],
    ["EDF", "A", "2023-04", 2150934],
    ["EDF", "A", "2023-05", 2145379],
    ["EDF", "B", "2023-05", 9437069],
    ["EDF", "A", "2023-06", 2140437],
    ["EDF", "B", "2023-06", 9437069],
    ["EDF", "A", "2023-07", 2134433],
    ["EDF","B", "2023-07", 9393434]
]
```

below is the desired output

| Name | Category | Date | Amount | DiffB | DiffA |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| ABC | B | 2023-04 | 1829540 | 0 | 0 |
| ABC | B | 2023-05 | 1829540 | 0 | 0 |
| ABC | B | 2023-06 | 12087873 | 10258333 | 0 |
| ABC | A | 2023-07 | 1782207 | 0 | 1782207 |
| ABC | B | 2023-07 | 10258333 | -1829540 | 0 |
| EDF | A | 2023-04 | 2150934 | 0 | 0 |
| EDF | A | 2023-05 | 2145379 | 0 | -5555 |
| EDF | B | 2023-05 | 9437069 | 9437069 | 0 |
| EDF | A | 2023-06 | 2140437 | 0 | -4942 |
| EDF | B | 2023-06 | 9437069 | 0 | 0 |
| EDF | A | 2023-07 | 2134433 | 0 | -6004 |
| EDF | B | 2023-07 | 9393434 | -43635 | 0 |

Dataset 02 for test

```
data = [
    ["EDF", "A", "2023-04", 2150934],
    ["EDF", "A", "2023-05", 2145379],
    ["EDF", "B", "2023-05", 9437069],
    ["EDF", "A", "2023-06", 2140437],
    ["EDF", "B", "2023-06", 9437069],
    ["EDF", "A", "2023-07", 2134433],
    ["EDF","B", "2023-07", 9393434],
    ["ABC", "B", "2023-04", 1829540],
    ["ABC", "B", "2023-05", 1829540],
    ["ABC", "B", "2023-06", 12087873],
    ["ABC", "A", "2023-07", 1782207],
    ["ABC", "B", "2023-07", 10258333],
    ["XYZ", "B", "2023-04", 1829540],
    ["XYZ", "B", "2023-05", 1829540],
    ["XYZ", "B", "2023-06", 12087873],
    ["XYZ", "A", "2023-07", 1782207],
    ["XYZ", "B", "2023-07", 10258333]
]
```

the output for data 02, as you can see data for client XYZ is same as client ABC. so, output in column DiffB and DiffA should be the same

| Name | Category | Date | Amount | DiffB | DiffA |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| ABC | B | 2023-04 | 1829540 | 0 | 0 |
| ABC | B | 2023-05 | 1829540 | 0 | 0 |
| ABC | B | 2023-06 | 12087873 | 10258333 | 0 |
| ABC | A | 2023-07 | 1782207 | 0 | 1782207 |
| ABC | B | 2023-07 | 10258333 | -1829540 | 0 |
| EDF | A | 2023-04 | 2150934 | 0 | 0 |
| EDF | A | 2023-05 | 2145379 | 0 | -5555 |
| EDF | B | 2023-05 | 9437069 | 9437069 | 0 |
| EDF | A | 2023-06 | 2140437 | 0 | -4942 |
| EDF | B | 2023-06 | 9437069 | 0 | 0 |
| EDF | A | 2023-07 | 2134433 | 0 | -6004 |
| EDF | B | 2023-07 | 9393434 | -43635 | 0 |
| XYZ | B | 2023-04 | 1829540 | 0 | 0 |
| XYZ | B | 2023-05 | 1829540 | 0 | 0 |
| XYZ | B | 2023-06 | 12087873 | 10258333 | 0 |
| XYZ | A | 2023-07 | 1782207 | 0 | 1782207 |
| XYZ | B | 2023-07 | 10258333 | -1829540 | 0 |

Comment: Is row 4 the first instance of 'A' in total? Or is there potentially some data for a month earlier than the exampble? Do you also want the first instance of 'B' to also not have a first difference of 0?

Comment: @Tyler thanks for trying this. row 4 is the first instance of A for that client, the data start on April 2023, for the first Month which is April I want zero because there is no data before that, would like same behavior for DiffB and DiffA, the variance from previous Month.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this:

```
       import pandas as pd

data = [
    ["ABC", "B", "2023-04", 1829540],
    ["ABC", "B", "2023-05", 1829540],
    ["ABC", "B", "2023-06", 12087873],
    ["ABC", "A", "2023-07", 1782207],
    ["ABC", "B", "2023-07", 10258333],
    ["EDF", "A", "2023-04", 2150934],
    ["EDF", "A", "2023-05", 2145379],
    ["EDF", "B", "2023-05", 9437069],
    ["EDF", "A", "2023-06", 2140437],
    ["EDF", "B", "2023-06", 9437069],
    ["EDF", "A", "2023-07", 2134433],
    ["EDF", "B", "2023-07", 9393434]
]

df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['Name', 'Category', 'Date', 'Amount'])

# Calculate differences for 'A' and 'B' category separately

df['DiffB'] = df[df['Category'] == 'B'].groupby('Name')['Amount'].diff().fillna(df['Amount'])
df['DiffA'] = df[df['Category'] == 'A'].groupby('Name')['Amount'].diff().fillna(df['Amount'])

# For rows not in the category 'A' or 'B', set 'DiffA' or 'DiffB' to 0
df['Category_shift'] = df['Category'].shift(-1)
df['DiffB'] = df.apply(lambda x: x['DiffB'] if (x['Category'] == 'B' and x['Category'] != x['Category_shift']) else 0, axis=1)
df['DiffA'] = df.apply(lambda x: x['DiffA'] if (x['Category'] == 'A' and x['Category'] != x['Category_shift']) else 0, axis=1)

print(df.drop(['Category_shift'], axis = 1))

Name Category     Date    Amount       DiffB      DiffA
0   ABC        B  2023-04   1829540         0.0        0.0
1   ABC        B  2023-05   1829540         0.0        0.0
2   ABC        B  2023-06  12087873  10258333.0        0.0
3   ABC        A  2023-07   1782207         0.0  1782207.0
4   ABC        B  2023-07  10258333  -1829540.0        0.0
5   EDF        A  2023-04   2150934         0.0        0.0
6   EDF        A  2023-05   2145379         0.0    -5555.0
7   EDF        B  2023-05   9437069   9437069.0        0.0
8   EDF        A  2023-06   2140437         0.0    -4942.0
9   EDF        B  2023-06   9437069         0.0        0.0
10  EDF        A  2023-07   2134433         0.0    -6004.0
11  EDF        B  2023-07   9393434    -43635.0        0.0
```

**Alt method using new example data**: In this code whenever category changes the diff value get populated. And it gets populated based on from which category to which category the values get changed. Hopefully this will finally resolve your problem.

```
    import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

data = [['ABC', 'B', '2023-04', 1829540, 0, 0],
        ['ABC', 'B', '2023-05', 1829540, 0, 0],
        ['ABC', 'B', '2023-06', 12087873, 10258333, 0],
        ['ABC', 'A', '2023-07', 1782207, 0, 1782207],
        ['ABC', 'B', '2023-07', 10258333, -1829540, 0],
        ['EDF', 'A', '2023-04', 2150934, 0, 0],
        ['EDF', 'A', '2023-05', 2145379, 0, -5555],
        ['EDF', 'B', '2023-05', 9437069, 9437069, 0],
        ['EDF', 'A', '2023-06', 2140437, 0, -4942],
        ['EDF', 'B', '2023-06', 9437069, 0, 0],
        ['EDF', 'A', '2023-07', 2134433, 0, -6004],
        ['EDF', 'B', '2023-07', 9393434, -43635, 0],
        ['XYZ', 'B', '2023-04', 1829540, 0, 0],
        ['XYZ', 'B', '2023-05', 1829540, 0, 0],
        ['XYZ', 'B', '2023-06', 12087873, 10258333, 0],
        ['XYZ', 'A', '2023-07', 1782207, 0, 1782207],
        ['XYZ', 'B', '2023-07', 10258333, -1829540, 0]]

df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['Name', 'Category', 'Date', 'Amount', 'DiffB', 'DiffA'])
df.drop(['DiffA', 'DiffB'], axis = 1, inplace = True)

# Get the previous and next category for comparison
df['Prev_Category'] = df.groupby('Name')['Category'].shift(1)
df['Next_Category'] = df.groupby('Name')['Category'].shift(-1)

# Calculate DiffB and DiffA using groupby and diff
df['DiffB'] = df[df['Category'] == 'B'].groupby('Name')['Amount'].diff().fillna(df['Amount'])
df['DiffA'] = df[df['Category'] == 'A'].groupby('Name')['Amount'].diff().fillna(df['Amount'])

# Create the final DiffB and DiffA columns based on conditions
df['DiffB_final'] = np.where(
    ((df['Category'] == 'B') & (df['Prev_Category'] == 'A')) | 
    ((df['Category'] == 'B') & (df['Next_Category'] == 'A')), 
    df['DiffB'], 
    0
)

df['DiffA_final'] = np.where(
    ((df['Category'] == 'A') & (df['Prev_Category'] == 'B')) | 
    ((df['Category'] == 'A') & (df['Next_Category'] == 'B')), 
    df['DiffA'], 
    0
)

# Drop temporary columns
df.drop(['Prev_Category', 'Next_Category', 'DiffB', 'DiffA'], axis=1, inplace=True)

print(df)

Name Category     Date    Amount  DiffB_final  DiffA_final
0   ABC        B  2023-04   1829540          0.0          0.0
1   ABC        B  2023-05   1829540          0.0          0.0
2   ABC        B  2023-06  12087873   10258333.0          0.0
3   ABC        A  2023-07   1782207          0.0    1782207.0
4   ABC        B  2023-07  10258333   -1829540.0          0.0
5   EDF        A  2023-04   2150934          0.0          0.0
6   EDF        A  2023-05   2145379          0.0      -5555.0
7   EDF        B  2023-05   9437069    9437069.0          0.0
8   EDF        A  2023-06   2140437          0.0      -4942.0
9   EDF        B  2023-06   9437069          0.0          0.0
10  EDF        A  2023-07   2134433          0.0      -6004.0
11  EDF        B  2023-07   9393434     -43635.0          0.0
12  XYZ        B  2023-04   1829540          0.0          0.0
13  XYZ        B  2023-05   1829540          0.0          0.0
14  XYZ        B  2023-06  12087873   10258333.0          0.0
15  XYZ        A  2023-07   1782207          0.0    1782207.0
16  XYZ        B  2023-07  10258333   -1829540.0          0.0
```

Comment: thanks for trying this. but the output is different.

Comment: when I try this code with 2 clients I get all values = zero.  I'm updating the data in the main question

Comment: @rossjim: my code showing correctly the answer you are expecting. If you expand your data (use the `data` structure I'm using), then it will be easier for us to help you.

Comment: @rossjim: Updated the answer based on your new dataset. My result is exactly matching with your expected result.

Comment: @rossjim: Glad I could help you! If you find my answer correct, will you please accept my answer? Thanks!

Comment: thanks for your help ragas much appreciated. I tried the code adding another client name adding same values and code doesnt work. I have no idea why.  I gonna add a data set 02.

Comment: @rossjim: What is your requirement? Is your requirement is whenever there's a change from one category to another the difference be taken? And this difference tracks from which category to which category the shift happened? If you don't explain your question with proper example, we can't help.

Comment: thanks for trying so hard on this ragas, I just need to get the Monthly difference by client and category. obviously my data set is way bigger and with lots of client, so I need to code to work for all clients.  I will try your new code, thanks again :)

Comment: I added the output for data 02. the values for client XYZ are the same as client ABC. so, the values for columns DiffB and DiffA should be exactly the same

Comment: @rossjim: I got the same result as you showed. But your data has some problem. Category is not correctly sorted. I used your exact data to get the exact result you are asking

Answer (score 0):

If you know which categories specifically start in later months I would do it as so:

```
data = [('ABC', 'B', '2023-04', 1829540),
       ('ABC', 'B', '2023-05', 1829540),
       ('ABC', 'B', '2023-06', 12087873),
       ('ABC', 'A', '2023-07', 1782207),
       ('ABC', 'B', '2023-07', 1025833)]

df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['Name', 'Category', 'Date', 'Amount'])
df['DiffB'] = df[df['Category'] == 'B'].groupby('Name')['Amount'].diff().fillna(0)
df['DiffA'] = df[df['Category'] == 'A'].groupby('Name')['Amount'].diff().fillna(df.Amount)
df[['DiffA','DiffB']] = df[['DiffA', 'DiffB']].fillna(0)
print(df)

  Name Category     Date    Amount       DiffB      DiffA
0  ABC        B  2023-04   1829540         0.0        0.0
1  ABC        B  2023-05   1829540         0.0        0.0
2  ABC        B  2023-06  12087873  10258333.0        0.0
3  ABC        A  2023-07   1782207         0.0  1782207.0
4  ABC        B  2023-07   1025833 -11062040.0        0.0
```

You just need to change the fillna() for the Categories that don't start in April

Comment: the thing is I have multiple clients and some dont have CatA neither CatB

Comment: in the Month of April I mean